# Error: invalid initial heap size, could not create virtual machine

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

При запуске с кнопки Run в Intellij-Idea вылетает ошибка:

Error: invalid initial heap size, could not create virtual machine

При этом при запуске тестов командой maven test тесты выполняются нормально.
Версия Java 11, 64 бит, IDE 2022.1.4

Comment: Какие у вас установлены опции виртуальной машины `-Xms`, `-Xmx`? См. [Configuring JVM options and platform properties](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties)  Также стоит проверить конфигурацию при запуске.